# SonarQube LDAP Plugin installed, but showing no changes

Tags: plugins, ldap, sonarqube

I'm running SonarQube 6.7.3 and installed the LDAP plugin.  I've followed all instructions and configuration and can confirm I'm getting the appropriate messages in the log after restarting:

> INFO org.sonar.INFO Security realm: LDAP ...
>
> INFO o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory Test LDAP connection: OK

However, after multiple SonarQube resets and server resets I don't see the option detailed in the install instructions:

> On log out users will be presented login page (/sessions/login), where
>   they can choose to login as technical user or a domain user by passing
>   appropriate credentials

LDAP logins also do not work.

I've seen other posts that say restarts helped, but this hasn't gotten me anywhere.  Any advice would be awesome!

Comment: Try setting the debug level to DEBUG/TRACE to gather more information.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is not working ? What happen when you authenticate with a LDAP user ? What happen when you authenticate with a local user ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam The regular, local user logs in fine.  Attempting to login with an LDAP user says "authentication failed".

Comment: Ok thanks, then could you check the server's log ?

Comment: From the last restart:  
2018.06.13 12:40:39 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP

2018.06.13 12:40:39 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://dc-02.igloosoftware.pvt: OK